How to handling multiple containers correctly?
so I'm kinda new to Docker so I am not sure how to handle multiple containers effectively. Currently, I have 2 container running using docker compose, one for backend APIs (express) and one for the db (postgresql), I will probably have one for the frontend once I start working on it as well.
The containers are working fine but I am still confused and have the following questions.
Should I leave the db container running then run sql query using docker exec, or should I have a sql script that runs every time I build the db again?
How should I use these containers for collaborations?
Should I just send the the config files or should I publish the images to docker hub and ask my team to pull it? If so, how does docker compose work if the images are pulled from docker hub?
Also, I have not deploy anything and its all running on localhost.
compose.yaml:
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:...@db:5432/carpool"
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d carpool -U postgres" ]
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ...
      POSTGRES_DB: carpool
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata: {}

backend.dockerfile:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install && npm install -g nodemon

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.mjs"]


As a first step here, I'd adopt a database-migration system, probably using what's built into Prisma or Sequelize.  Do you have that already?  You should not need docker exec to interact with your database, and you shouldn't normally need to delete and recreate it.

Have only heard of Prisma but I have people said it's better to not use any if you are familiar with SQL already. Which one do you prefer in your opinion? Also could you clarify why I should not use docker exec?
Thank you

You need to manually run docker exec, so it's a step that it's possible to forget.  docker exec requires a running container so you need to bring the system up in a not-running state to run migrations, then restart things.  Running docker commands in general requires administrative-level privileges over the entire system.  I'd generally recommend reserving docker exec for actual debugging.
